# Melt multiindex dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, datareader

I am trying to

The data looks like the following:

```
Attributes  Adj Close       Close           High            Low             Open            Volume
Symbols     AAPL    ACN     AAPL    ACN     AAPL    ACN     AAPL    ACN     AAPL    ACN     AAPL    ACN
Date                                                
2002-01-02  1.444668    19.703959   1.664286    26.209999   1.664286    26.910000   1.568571    25.950001   1.575000    26.900000   132374200.0     900500.0
2002-01-03  1.462029    19.087507   1.684286    25.389999   1.696429    26.270000   1.626429    25.299999   1.642857    26.230000   153001800.0     698200.0
2002-01-04  1.468849    20.824106   1.692143    27.700001   1.710714    28.200001   1.642143    25.240000   1.667143    25.389999   102494000.0     2708500.0
```

I tried using melt but somehow I can get it only working with one column Adj Close:

```
    Date    Ticker     Adj Close 
0   2002-01-02  AAPL    1.444668
1   2002-01-03  AAPL    1.462029
2   2002-01-04  AAPL    1.468849
3   2002-01-07  AAPL    1.419867
4   2002-01-08  AAPL    1.401886
```

the code is:

```
df = pd.melt(df_market_data['Adj Close'].reset_index(), id_vars='Date', value_name='Adj Close', var_name='minor').rename(columns={'minor': 'Ticker'})
```

When trying doing it with all of them:

```
Adj Close       Close           High            Low             Open            Volume
```

it is not working:

```
df = pd.melt(df_market_data.reset_index(), id_vars='Date', value_name=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], var_name='minor').rename(columns={'minor': 'Ticker'})
```

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import datetime as dt

ticker_list = ['AAPL','ACN']

start_date = dt.datetime(2002,1,1).date()
end_date = dt.datetime.now().date() - dt.timedelta(days=1)

df_market_data = pdr.DataReader(ticker_list, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)

df = pd.melt(df_market_data['Adj Close'].reset_index(), id_vars='Date', value_name='Adj Close', var_name='minor').rename(columns={'minor': 'Ticker'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack() function is used to stack the prescribed level(s) from columns to index. Here the index on level one was used to receive the proper output and the dedicated dataframe output

```
df = df_market_data.stack(level = 1).reset_index(level = [0, 1], drop = False).reset_index()
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.